# Can not force the style of element

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am using a Html template to create my website , but I have problem with the area between  slider and header.
the header take long height so I am trying to change it by adding 
`style="height:49px !important "` to the div header 
but when I opening the page with chrome , the header still get long height and when I tried to check from Inspect section , I noticed that my style code which I did

> {height:49}

is disabled and there is a value which is appearing in

```
element.style {
height:103px
}
```

I don't know from where this value is coming and the value 103px is changing from screen to another , but I checked all css files to check about it , but I found nothings. please help me how can I disable this automatic header height value

Comment: how you are changing the height of div and is it after page load or before that? Also, is there any script or plugin used which recalculate the header height? Can you reproduce this issue on code snippet or jsfiddle or any online recreation tool?

Comment: I would suggest to go to the style (.css) files of the HTML template, find the set value there and change it. Or you can assign a class to your div and add a definition for that class to the stylesheet.

Comment: Hi @MAJED BW, Could you add the HTML and CSS code, I think the value is coming from external or internal CSS.

Comment: Please add HTML and CSS, otherwise we won't be able to help.

Comment: Please go read [ask] and [mre], and edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The `element.style` will be more part of your HTML like `<span style="height: 103px;">` than your CSS. It could also be added later via JavaScript. Please check these files instead of your CSS.

Modern browsers also allow breakpoints on attribute modifications to a DOM element.